# flutter error not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program

Tags: flutter, dart, hybrid-mobile-app

I downloaded flutter and it works just fine, but I open it today and I get this error anyone knows how can I fix it
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwzTw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Goto Control Panel-->System and Security-->System**

**Then follow the steps**

[image]

**After step 3 this windows will come up then add the path of flutter in my case mine is located at E:\flutter\bin change this to your flutter installed path**

[image]

**After all  steps restart your code editor**

Comment: I did that but still doesn't work but then I uninstall the packages then installed and now it works. Do you know why it work when I uninstalled?

Comment: i am not sure,i need more info,after you set up the path,then you try to run the command what it  says,or did you restart the code editor @XAN

Comment: no, I just deleted the package then download it again then I set up the path then it worked, but I get confused why it works after that? and I want to prevent this error, so it didn't happen to me again

Comment: i am not sure about this,i had same problem after i setup the path,then it worked without uninstall,it may be path is incorrect or something @XAN